# How to reset/change expired password for DB2 Content Manager 8.4.1

Tags: windows, db2

I had installed IBM DB2 Content Manager 8.4.1 months ago and now I wanted to access it to continue some more work.

But when I try to log in using System Administration Client, it tells me the password is expired. The error is:

```
DGL0394A: Error in ::DriverManager.getConnection;[jcc][t4][2012][11248][3.50.152]
Connection authorization failure occurred. Reason: Password expired.
ERRORCODE=-4214,SQLSTATE=28000 (STATE) : ; 
[SERVER = icmnsldb, USERID = icmadmin, SQL RC = -4214, SQL STATE = 28000]
```

I've tried looking thru the config files, using the java update command line..  and I can't find a way to change or reset the password. I can't use System Administration Client to change the passwords, since it won't log me in to begin with.  Any other method I can use to reset/change the password for a DB2 CM user?

Comment: For Linux operational system check it out: https://serverfault.com/questions/190067/non-expiring-password-on-linux-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Client for Windows on a desktop machine and not the eClient to login. It will directly notify about a expired password and you can set the new password immediately.

Answer (score 2):

DB2 uses the operating system to authenticate users, so you need to use the OS tools to reset the icmadmin user's password.  Your post is tagged as Windows, so look for the icmadmin user in either the local machine or in the domain if your server belongs to a domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Docker, you need to perform a [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) into the DB2 container (Linux) and then change the password for the local user that you are trying to log in to DB2 with. In my case, the name of the user was "myuser". I changed the password by executing

```
passwd myuser
```

Note that you are root by default (OS level user) when you `exec` into the container. You may use the following command to use a different OS-level username:

```
docker exec -u username <containerName> /bin/sh
```

Comment: This did help me!
In addition, if you're using the Docker Desktop, just navigate to the Terminal tab then enter `passwd your-user`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I logged in as root and chaged the password for db2 user by passwd . and changed in the WAS console. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, click on start > Control Panel > User Accounts > User Accounts > Manage User Accounts.

Here, select the DB2 username and click on Reset Password.